# Erro ao ler página html com Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, codificação-de-caracteres, windows-phone, html-agility-pack

Estou lendo uma página HTML utilizando o [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex). Executo o código no notebook e funciona perfeitamente. O problema é quando executo o mesmo no Windows Phone 7.1.

Caracteres acentuados (ç) estão codificados. E o mais estranho é que o mesmo código é utilizado para baixar duas páginas, as duas possuem palavras coma acentos, mas apenas uma delas não retorna o texto como exibido na página.

Código para carregar o arquivo

```
    CustomEncoding enc = new CustomEncoding();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    document.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = enc; //CustomEncoding.Unicode;
```

Código para executar o *download*

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    //CustomEncoding is "iso-8859-2"
    web.LoadCompleted += web_LoadCompleted;
    web.LoadAsync(_filme.Detalhes, enc);// GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Utilizo a propriedade `InnerHtml` para recuperar o texto.

```
    void web_LoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
    {
        HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = CustomEncoding.Unicode;// System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        //document.LoadHtml(e.Document);
        HtmlNode html = GetNodeByName(e.Document.DocumentNode, "html");
        HtmlNode body = GetNodeByName(html, "body");
        HtmlNode allOut = GetNodeById(body, "all-out");
        HtmlNode allIn = GetNodeById(allOut, "all-in");
        HtmlNode content = GetNodeById(allIn, "content");
        HtmlNode lojas = GetNodeById(content, "lojas");
        HtmlNode leftSideMovie = GetNodeById(lojas, "left-side-movie");
        HtmlNode infoLoja = GetNodeById(leftSideMovie, "info-loja");

        HtmlNode censuraNode = GetNodeById(infoLoja, "censura-3d-leg-dub");
        HtmlNode sinopseNode = GetNodeById(infoLoja, "sinopse");
        HtmlNode marmota = GetNodeByNameAndClass(sinopseNode, "div", "margin_20b");
        HtmlNode preSinopseNode = marmota;

        //percorrer todos os filhos até encontrar a ultima marmota
        while (marmota != null)
        {
            preSinopseNode = marmota;
            marmota = GetNodeByNameAndClass(marmota, "div", "margin_20b");
        }

        string sinopse;
        try
        {
            //TODO: remover o try e refatorar para armazenar cada chamada de metodo em uma variavel
            //tentar com o span
            _filme.Descricao = GetNodeByName(GetNodeByName(preSinopseNode, "p"), "span").InnerHtml;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _filme.Descricao = GetNodeByName(preSinopseNode, "p").InnerHtml;
        }
    }
```

[Página utilizada](http://www.iguatemifortaleza.com.br/cinema/filme/2868/boyhood_da_infancia_a_juventude)

Vou adicionar apenas um dos métodos, pois todos são muito semelhantes.

```
    private HtmlNode GetNodeByName(HtmlNode root, string node)
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode link in root.ChildNodes)
            if (link.Name.Equals(node))
                return link;
        return null;
    }
```

Um dos links que fala sobre [CustomEncoding](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/394082)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mais uma vez a minha teoria se mostra correta.
`Quando você não consegue encontrar uma solução, é provável que esteja bem na frente do seu nariz.`

Essa foi a solução, sem precisar configurar o encoding.

```
    System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode
```

Answer (score 1):

Estive fazendo um simples leitor de html e csv, onde encontrei o mesmo problema.
Resolvi meu problema substituindo o **UTF8** por **iso-8859-1**, então te sugiro substituir o teu Enconding da seguinte forma

Código para carregar o arquivo

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
```

Código para executar o download

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.LoadCompleted += web_LoadCompleted;
web.LoadAsync(_filme.Detalhes, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Maiores informações sobre os Enconding tu pode encontrar no link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: Não funcionou, Paulo. Você fez no Windows Phone 7.1?

Comment: Não, foi console aplication.

Comment: Pois é,  o meu código funcionou perfeitamente console,  com UTF8, o problema é apenas no Windows Phone.

Comment: Será que o Windows phone não usa um Encoding diferente?

Comment: Encontrei perguntas semelhantes no so em inglês,  mas não consegui resolver.  Dizia q teria q utilizar um pograma pra gerar uma class de encoding.  Mas o estranho é que isso ta acontecendo com uma página e outra não.

Comment: https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/394082

Comment: Eu nunca trabalhei com custom encoding. Mas parece ser o caminho.

Comment: Tu não teria como publicar um exemplo do projeto que esta fazendo?

Comment: Já tentei iso-8859-1, iso-8859-2, Encoding.GetEncoding, UTF8,Unicode e ainda não entendo o que está acontecendo.

Posso sim. vou preparar aqui

Comment: Atualizado, Paulo.